# Query on other query linq

Tags: sql, linq

Just assume a simple example:I have two table and use this query:

```
select * 
from People 
where PersonGuid = (select PersonGuid from Sellers where Guid = '')
```

How can I write this query with linq?

I tried this:

```cs
var person = from p in loginContext.Person where p.PersonGuid = 
    (loginContext.Seller.Where(s => s.Guid == sellerGuid).FirstOrDefaultAsync());
```

but that's wrong.
What is the right way to write it?

Comment: hint, google `Join`

Comment: Do you have a foreign-key relationship between these two tables? Have you represented this in Entity Framework? What version of Entity Framework are you even using? It should just be `person.Seller` or `person.Sellers` depending on how you defined it (1:1 or 1:many).

Comment: yes.. primary-key in people is personGuid and foreign-key in sellers is same.. relationship is defined (1:n)

Comment: The SQL query is also wrong because you can't guarantee that the subquery returns only one element. And again, which data access library are you working with and which version and what does the relationship between both entities look like? That's vital information that can't be omitted in questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to rewrite your `SQL` query as

```
select * 
from People AS PE
JOIN
Sellers AS Sellers
ON PE.PersonGuid = SE.PersonGuid
WHERE
SE.Guid = ''
```

then the `LINQ` becomes a little more obvious:

```cs
var person = (from p in loginContext.Person
             join s in loginContext.Seller on p.PersonGuid  equals s.PersonGuid 
             where s.guid == ""
             select p)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Although your SQL would suggest `FirstOrDefault` is not required.

Warning - not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try using LINQ JOIN clause.

It should be something like:

```
from p in loginContext.Person
join s in loginContext.Seller on new { p.PersonGuid = s.Guid }
where s.Guid = sellerGuid
```

You can know more about LINQ JOIN here -> [Microsoft C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that `select PersonGuid from Sellers where Guid = ''` will provide a single value no matter what, otherwise your SQL statement would fail.

Accepted answer works, but if you want a solution that keeps the spirit of the SQL query, you can rely on `Any` function. Something along the following:

```
var person = await loginContext.Person
    .Where(p => loginContext.Sellers
                      .Any(s => s.PersonGuid == p.PersonGuid && s.Guid = ""))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I expect this to be transformed into an SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS which is similar to your initial query.